# How to find out where is from broadcastReceiver calling?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm working on a combination of few big projects which I'm not much familiar. I have a Local broadcast events and it register from the script.

```
context.registerReceiver(stReceiver, stIntents);

private BroadcastReceiver stReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
};
```

I need to find out where is this broadcastReceiver calling from? Is there any way to find out from which class `.sendBroadcast(intent);` calls?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, whether this works or not but give it a try.
Use Log statement to print `intent.getClass().getName()` in `onReceive` function.
Since the intent is passed from calling class it will provide the class name.

Comment: Thanks. It is not giving the calling class name. BTW you are the only person answer to the question eventhough the solution isn't correct.

Comment: this call class that associated to object. so not correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `context.registerReceiver(stReceiver, stIntents);` itself is `.sendBroadcast(intent);` here.

`.sendBroadcast(intent);` is used in global broadcast. For local `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)` is sufficient to start the broadcast.

```
 I need to find out where is this broadcastReceiver calling from?
```

So in your case `context.registerReceiver(stReceiver, stIntents);` itself is the starting point.

For more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: Thanks But I'm in doubt.  Local broadcast also has a method called  sendBroadcast(Intent intent) in API. So what is the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

You Can check the action for the Intent. and search the action in your project

String action =intent.getAction();

Answer (score -1):

```
You can put check 

like this

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
//Do your part

}
}

In place of Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON you can use your own action you mention in the intent filter while registering a receiver
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this is not I'm looking for.